# How can i see the json that i got back from the http post call ?

Tags: android

I wrote some simple application that make http call ( Post ). 
The Response can be one of the option 
          - Xml 
          - Json

I see ( in debug mode ) that i get some response from the server - but i don't see any xml or/and any json format.

How can i get the xml/json format ?

Comment: test ( in your browser ) if your WS is returning a json or not , and then

Comment: there are two option - using xml or using the json ... i need to choose what method i will call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to print out the result of `EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())`

Answer (score 3):

Get Http Response in Response object then getEnttity from response, Using enttity's inputstream convert that stream into string..

```
 String result="";
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
 httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,    HTTP.UTF_8));
 // Execute HTTP Post Request
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
 // get response entity
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
 // convert entity response to string
 if (entity != null) {
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            // convert stream to string
            result = convertStreamToString(is); 
            result = result.replace("\n", "");
        }
 Log.e("Response from the server:",result)
```

And for **convertStreamToString(is);**

```
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
sb.append(line + "\n");
}
is.close();
return sb.toString();
}
```